# Problem in replacing the_content with the_excerpt()

Tags: php, loop, the-content, excerpt

I want to add **read more** to a blog. For that I need to replace the function `the_content()`. I found it in the loop file and replaced it with `the_excerpt()` but still posts are being shown of full length. Please help out.

**EDIT:**
[Here](http://pricelessproject.com/wordpress/) is the site. The read more is added now(I replaced all the occurences of the_content with the_excerpt). It gave rise to a new problem. All the links on the page are not working correctly. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have replaced it in the correct template file?

I found a useful way to tell by adding this to the functions.php file:

```
<?php
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'adminbar_print_template' );
function adminbar_print_template() {
    global $template, $current_user, $wp_admin_bar;

    get_currentuserinfo();
        /* If you have more than one user deny. Be sure to use your user ID! */
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && $current_user->ID != '1' )
        return;
    if ( is_admin_bar_showing() )
        $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
            'parent' => false,
            'id' => 'template',
            'title' => $template,
            'href' => '#'
        ));
    else
        print_r( $template );
}
?>
```

If you have the Show Admin Bar settings set to "show when viewing site", it will output the current template file being used on the page you are viewing. Another possibility could be that your theme uses a loop.php file, and you will need to modify it for the excerpt.

**TIP:**
Add this to your functions.php file so the "Read More" tags are actually links to the posts:

```
   function new_excerpt_more($more) {
   global $post;
   return '… <a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . 'Read More &raquo;' . '</a>';
   }
   add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Comment: I tried the way wordpress.org suggested. Now I am stuck with a weird problem, the posts do have read more option but ALL the links on the blog are not working correctly. can you help out? Have a look http://pricelessproject.com/wordpress/

Comment: I viewed your site and they seemed to work correctly. What page/links specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: Its http://pricelessproject.com/wordpress/ . I tried again but NONE of the links are working correctly. I am being redirected to the homepage.For example, click read more on any of the post and you will be redirected to the homepage. Same problem with all the links

Comment: I see now. Have you checked to make sure you removed all the old read more code? You need to remove what you had and replace it with what I've posted. In your template files, you need to put <?php the_excerpt(); ?>